# Splitting a .ts file

Tags: video, software-rec

I'm looking for some software that allows me to split a .ts file according to time.

For example, I'd like to split a file into two parts with the second part starting from 2:30 in the original .ts file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I use [TSSplitter](http://www.ffprojects.net/tssplitter/tssplitter.htm) and am quite satisfied with it.

> **TSSplitter** is intended for splitting and joining large MPEG Transport
>   Streams containing any kind of stream encoding, including MPEG2 and
>   H.264 (*), to burn them to DVD. The advantage compared to other
>   similar tools is that you can later join the files and get a file
>   that's 100% like the origninal source file, so you get no klicks or
>   image glitches on the join position, and you can for example re-seed
>   the file via BitTorrent.
>
> **TSSplitter** also lets you preview the beginning and ending of each
>   partial file, so you can check that the file is not split in the
>   middle of a sentence. You can select from different naming schemes for
>   the partial files or make your own scheme.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I googled this issue before I post here and I found this software but this asks for the sizes to split according to... not the time, is there anyway that I can do what I want using this software?

Comment: ???? still waiting please

Comment: is your file music file? video file?

Comment: if it's music you can use visual mp3 splitter joiner. It works quite nicely. Sorry for TSSpliter, I was quite convinced that it worked for time splitting but after checking on mine I realized not.

Comment: Actually it's a video file that's recorded from an HD TV channel, anyway TSSplitter works fine on my files according to size.. but I need it for time, thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: See this...http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/326450-How-to-split-a-TS-video-file-based-on-time-(not-file-size!)